# Crystal Report Installation in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have installed crystal report for visual studio 2010 from SAP corporation. Still when i open a crystal report for my project it shows me the following screen. How do I solve this problem?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/syiYG.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

Try the complete package and see. I had the same problem and this solved it. http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_2.exe